# PHP explode get specfic index value in one line

Tags: php, arrays, line, explode

I want to do

```
<?php 
$str = "I want to access 2nd or 3rd index in one line";
echo explode(" ",$str)[2];
?>
```

We can access first index easily using

```
stristr($str," ",true);  //For php version >= 5.3
```

or

```
$foo = array_shift(explode(':', $foo));
```

or

```
list($str) = explode(" ", $str);
```

**BUT**

**HOW TO ACCESS SPECIFIC INDEX [1],[2] OR [3] IN ONE LINE???**

Comment: You can only do `echo explode(" ",$str)[2];` in PHP >= 5.4 as I remember.

Comment: yes, you are correct, i just tested it in 5.4, any other good solution to work with other version will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**5.4+**

```
<?php echo explode(" ","I want to access 2nd or 3rd index in one line")[2]; ?>
```

Comment: He wants to have it working in 5.3 :) see the comments beneath the OP's post.

Comment: Those comments were posted after the answer

Answer (score 0):

for second

```
strtok($string, " "); echo strtok(" ");
```

or third

```
strtok($string, " "); strtok(" "); echo strtok(" ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this to get specific index value

```
<?php 
  $str = "Iam want to access 2nd or 3rd index in one line";
  $val = explode(" ",$str);
  echo $val[3];
?>
```